# Too broad for question without good answer?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41714686/3950370), which got later put on hold for being too broad. I read the description of the reason, which says 'There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format'. I read a lot on SO and I also answered some questions, but I would consider myself still a newbie, so I am a little bit confused about this flag.

For me, 'too broad' questions are questions like 'How can I read a file of this format?' or 'I want a graphical user interface with three buttons', because even if the technology is defined (by text or tag), there are a lot of different ways to achieve this.

In this case, there is no other suggestion, the solution is not trivial and I can't find any good solution (instead of the mentioned 'too many possible answers'). Is this about the missing language constraint?

To be honest, for me this question is more 'off-topic' and touches the borderline between StackOverflow and SuperUser stack exchange than being 'too broad', since it requires a way how to access an administration tool.

EDIT: I recognized a downvote on my answer before I saw the 'on hold' state, so I asked for better ideas or reasons to criticise my answer. Is a question 'on hold' a reason to downvote or undo an upvote or do you think there was another reason to downvote?

Comment: see also: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: I find it borderline too broad and borderline off topic, because there are probably more than one possibility in solving it and it appears to not be related to programming, yet he talks about CMD and some scripting.

Comment: *"Is a question 'on hold' a reason to downvote"* – No. If somebody downvoted your answer based on the question, that was unreasonable. But then again, we have no idea who voted or why they did so.

Comment: About the question… it's not *great*, but it's not unreasonable either IMO. It would help if the OP posted the things they already tried to narrow it down somewhat. But overall, there likely is *one or two* APIs that can be called to achieve the desired result, and even if they can be called from many different languages, the approach is likely the same for all. So, doesn't seem unreasonably broad to me.

Comment: Well, I get the point on not asking "Is it possible to ..." and I am sorry, if this is considered a duplicate, but I read some questions on the 'too broad' flag here on Meta SO and they did not really suit my case, so I asked. It seems to me like the question would not be too broad, if the question contained my answer (describing what he tried to achieve this).

Comment: @deceze: Thanks, of course we don't know the reason for the downvote, but another user commented 'this likely where the down-vote came from', so I wanted to ask.

Comment: There are always different opinions about how things *should* be handled… I tend to disagree with the comment of that user. You're just caught in the crossfire. ;)

Comment: It is "too broad" because it asks someone to implement the entire solution, which would involve writing a non-trivial amount of code—too long and too complicated for a single answer. Not to pick on you, but your answer is a perfect example of why this type of question is problematic and needs to be closed. You posted some "ideas" as if they were an answer, but they don't actually answer the question and do not contain the solution to the problem. They might be helpful, but they're not an answer, and that's not how the Stack Overflow model works.

Comment: "Is a question 'on hold' a reason to downvote or undo an upvote or do you think there was another reason to downvote?" You got a comment from deceze about this but I think more needs to be said. I don't agree with downvoting an answer *only* because the question has been closed. However, bad questions tend to attract bad answers. It is not unreasonable to downvote answers that provide only generic guidance towards solving a problem. Questions that are too broad do tend to get such answers. It may be that another user sees this way and decided to downvote your answer. Just a possibility.

Comment: @Servy Yes that's what I was saying.

Comment: @Louis Sorry, missed a "not" in your comment.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I should probably avoid double negatives.